# Installing moodle on Ubuntu

Tags: php, apache, moodle

SO I'm trying to install Moodle using Ubuntu and I followed the instructions from https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/how-to-install-moodle-on-ubuntu-server-2004/ , but when I type localhost/moodle on my browser, it just displays the PHP code which I'll add.  I should be displayed with the Moodle installation steps right? I can't imagine it would be a problem with Moodle itself but rather a PHP issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<?php
// This file is part of Moodle - http://moodle.org/
//
// Moodle is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
// it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
// the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
// (at your option) any later version.
//
// Moodle is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
// but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
// MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
// GNU General Public License for more details.
//
// You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
// along with Moodle.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

/**
 * Moodle frontpage.
 *
 * @package    core
 * @copyright  1999 onwards Martin Dougiamas (http://dougiamas.com)
 * @license    http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html GNU GPL v3 or later
 */

if (!file_exists('./config.php')) {
    header('Location: install.php');
    die;
}

require_once('config.php');
require_once($CFG->dirroot .'/course/lib.php');
require_once($CFG->libdir .'/filelib.php');

redirect_if_major_upgrade_required();

$urlparams = array();
if (!empty($CFG->defaulthomepage) && ($CFG->defaulthomepage == HOMEPAGE_MY) && optional_param('redirect', 1, PARAM_BOOL) === 0) {
    $urlparams['redirect'] = 0;
}
$PAGE->set_url('/', $urlparams);
$PAGE->set_pagelayout('frontpage');
$PAGE->set_other_editing_capability('moodle/course:update');
$PAGE->set_other_editing_capability('moodle/course:manageactivities');
$PAGE->set_other_editing_capability('moodle/course:activityvisibility');

// Prevent caching of this page to stop confusion when changing page after making AJAX changes.
$PAGE->set_cacheable(false);

require_course_login($SITE);

$hasmaintenanceaccess = has_capability('moodle/site:maintenanceaccess', context_system::instance());

// If the site is currently under maintenance, then print a message.
if (!empty($CFG->maintenance_enabled) and !$hasmaintenanceaccess) {
    print_maintenance_message();
}

$hassiteconfig = has_capability('moodle/site:config', context_system::instance());

if ($hassiteconfig && moodle_needs_upgrading()) {
    redirect($CFG->wwwroot .'/'. $CFG->admin .'/index.php');
}

// If site registration needs updating, redirect.
\core\hub\registration::registration_reminder('/index.php');

if (get_home_page() != HOMEPAGE_SITE) {
    // Redirect logged-in users to My Moodle overview if required.
    $redirect = optional_param('redirect', 1, PARAM_BOOL);
    if (optional_param('setdefaulthome', false, PARAM_BOOL)) {
        set_user_preference('user_home_page_preference', HOMEPAGE_SITE);
    } else if (!empty($CFG->defaulthomepage) && ($CFG->defaulthomepage == HOMEPAGE_MY) && $redirect === 1) {
        redirect($CFG->wwwroot .'/my/');
    } else if (!empty($CFG->defaulthomepage) && ($CFG->defaulthomepage == HOMEPAGE_USER)) {
        $frontpagenode = $PAGE->settingsnav->find('frontpage', null);
        if ($frontpagenode) {
            $frontpagenode->add(
                get_string('makethismyhome'),
                new moodle_url('/', array('setdefaulthome' => true)),
                navigation_node::TYPE_SETTING);
        } else {
            $frontpagenode = $PAGE->settingsnav->add(get_string('frontpagesettings'), null, navigation_node::TYPE_SETTING, null);
            $frontpagenode->force_open();
            $frontpagenode->add(get_string('makethismyhome'),
                new moodle_url('/', array('setdefaulthome' => true)),
                navigation_node::TYPE_SETTING);
        }
    }
}

// Trigger event.
course_view(context_course::instance(SITEID));

$PAGE->set_pagetype('site-index');
$PAGE->set_docs_path('');
$editing = $PAGE->user_is_editing();
$PAGE->set_title($SITE->fullname);
$PAGE->set_heading($SITE->fullname);
$courserenderer = $PAGE->get_renderer('core', 'course');
echo $OUTPUT->header();

$siteformatoptions = course_get_format($SITE)->get_format_options();
$modinfo = get_fast_modinfo($SITE);
$modnamesused = $modinfo->get_used_module_names();

// Print Section or custom info.
if (!empty($CFG->customfrontpageinclude)) {
    // Pre-fill some variables that custom front page might use.
    $modnames = get_module_types_names();
    $modnamesplural = get_module_types_names(true);
    $mods = $modinfo->get_cms();

    include($CFG->customfrontpageinclude);

} else if ($siteformatoptions['numsections'] > 0) {
    echo $courserenderer->frontpage_section1();
}
// Include course AJAX.
include_course_ajax($SITE, $modnamesused);

echo $courserenderer->frontpage();

if ($editing && has_capability('moodle/course:create', context_system::instance())) {
    echo $courserenderer->add_new_course_button();
}
echo $OUTPUT->footer();
```

I looked at the modules in my httpd.conf file,  but when adding "LoadModule php_module modules/libphp.so" apache throws an error when attempting to restart.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the php is installed properly or not. You can check the same by running `php -v` in the terminal.
If it is installed and all needed php modules for moodle are there on the system, please run the following command and ensure the file looks like below.

`sudo nano /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf`

The file should look like this (The sequence of file extension matters a lot)

[Sample File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKQCy.png)

After ensuring / editing file as per above, restart the apache2 server with
`sudo systemctl reload apache2` and try to open moodle. It should work fine!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! Although I am running Apache from source, not apache2. Nonetheless, I already had index.php added to the Directory index but still a no go.

Answer (score 0):

Please search in Apache configs for `DocumentRoot` setting.
This setting contains the root directory where apache starts running from.
In apache2 the default root directory is \var\www\html, and the apache2 settings file location is \etc\apache2\sites-available\default-ssl.conf. maybe it's similar in Apache.
So you need to locate moodle directory based on `DocumentRoot` value. or change this setting value.